# Executing click function after redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

How do I execute click function on the "about" page after redirecting the pages for each link from the "home" page?

```js
function redirectcontact() {
  // Command to execute when on about.php     
  document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();
}

function redirectfaq() {
  // Command to execute when on about.php
  document.getElementById("clickfaq").click();
}
```

```html
<a class="whitelink" href="about.php" onclick="redirectcontact()">Contact Us</a>
<a class="whitelink" href="about.php" onclick="redirectfaq()">FAQ</a>
```

Comment: I think you've got your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it is possible with this, but I have a rather different way:

```js
function alertThenRedirect(){
  alert("You are being redirected to example.com");
  redirect();
}

function redirect(){
  window.location.assign("https://www.google.com");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="alertThenRedirect()">Redirect</a>
```

Actually, you don't even need an `a` tag in the above code, but it's just for demo.